# How to delete a 'Locked' folder on a 2nd internal HDD

Tags: hard-drive, mate

I have just installed 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver) MATE 1.20.1 64-bit on `/dev/sdb` HDD. The additional installed second HDD `/dev/sdb`, which was used for Back-Ups from a previous LM MATE OS, has the issue I am posting about. As I am overjoyed with this 'Ubuntu MATE' OS there is no going back to LM on this machine now. But, I do want to keep all the data stored on the second HDD `/dev/sdb` except for the one 'Locked' folder which was used by 'timeshift'.

My ability with MATE Terminal is very limited but if anyone experienced with Terminal could guide me through the process to remove this 'Locked' folder, I would very much appreciate your guidance.

The 'timeshift' **Properties > Permissions** show the Owner: root and also the Group: root

At the bottom of the greyed out Permissions dialogue box it also states:

> You are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissions.

Following Tejas Lotlikar's guidance, this is what appeared in Terminal after entering the command in his Step 1: List mount-able devices

```
myusername@Akoya-E7216:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for myusername: 
Disk /dev/loop0: 7.9 MiB, 8310784 bytes, 16232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 86.3 MiB, 90443776 bytes, 176648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 88.5 MiB, 92778496 bytes, 181208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 15.2 MiB, 15921152 bytes, 31096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 89.1 MiB, 93417472 bytes, 182456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 16 KiB, 16384 bytes, 32 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x17477a66

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 234440703 234438656 111.8G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
myusername@Akoya-E7216:~$
```

Hope this may help with typing the correct command to get rid of that locked timeshift folder on the sdb HDD.

Many thanks to Tejas Lotlikar and his very helpful guidance, this issue is now resolved. Also a well deserved 'Thank You' to Zanna for your awesome editing skills.

Comment: You may open a terminal and run: `sudo rm -r /path/to/locked_folder`. Make sure you enter the correct path, because a wrong sudo command can have bad consequences.

Comment: Did you create a NEW name for the admin user for that new system?  If so you need to mount the disk with that new user. Otherwise did you tell the installer to mount that disk? If so it is now owned by root and needs to be unlock with `sudo chown $USER:$USER /mountpoint`. Make sure to use the correct directory for /mountpoint ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: List mount-able devices

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

In my case I get:

[image: fdisk output]

Step 2: Create a directory to mount to

```
sudo mkdir /media/external
```

Step 3: Mount the drive now

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdc1 /media/external -o  uid=1000,gid=100,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
```

Replace `ntfs` with the `type`,  `/dev/sdc1` with the `device`

Finally remove the locked folder using the command `sudo rm -r /media/external/locked_folder_name`

## Note: Use `rm` command with caution. Make sure you have selected the correct folder name